# Почему специалист по информационной безопасности получает так мало?

Tags: безопасность, frontend

Посмотрев среднюю з/п специалиста ИБ, я увидел какие-то 50 тыс.руб.

Почему специалист по ИБ получает так мало по сравнению с тем же front-end разработчиком? (90 тыс.руб)

Comment: Это ж Россия, здесь всем плевать на безопасность

Comment: Зарплата специалиста по информационной безопасности зависит от выполняемых функций. Поэтому смотрите не только на зарплату, но и на требования к специалисту на эту зарплату. С front-end так же, чем выше зарплата, тем больше с вас будут спрашивать.

Answer (score 1):

Цена на рынке образуется по законам спроса и предложения и ничего личного. Мало или много это как оценивают услугу на рынке. Как говорится в фильме Кто не работает тот ест учись студент. Обидно что врач проучившись столько лет может зарабатывать меньше таксиста но это совсем другое.
Конечно если рынок есть и он подразумевает свободную конкуренцию и однородность, но зачастую это игра кому повезет а кому нет.
Потому что среднее это не совсем объективная величина.

Вот 100 иб с зарплатой 20 000 и 80 000
И 2 фронта с зарплатой по 80 000 и 100000

Да в среднем сейчас это так но где гарантии что когда фронтендов станет 100 средняя зарплата не упадет до 10 000. Прогноз рынка и его объяснения очень сложная штука. Но имейте в виду что хороший специалист всегда будет в цене.